# Is there a good math/stats library for Scala?

Tags: scala, math, statistics

I'm looking for a good open source library for scala for math and statistics. Hopefully something like Apache Math or Colt, but implemented in Scala.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It might help to explain why you're after a library implemented in Scala, rather than one that's merely usable from Scala.

Comment: Actually I started to use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/ and it is easy to use and works fine in Scala.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Yes, there are some:

### [Scalalab](http://code.google.com/p/scalalab/)

> The ScalaLab project aims to provide an efficient scientific
> programming environment for the Java Virtual Machine. The scripting
> language is based on the Scala programming language enhanced with high
> level scientific operators and with an integrated environment that
> provides a Matlab-like working style.
>
> The scripting code
> is extremely fast, close to Java (sometimes slower, sometimes faster),
> and usually faster from equivalent Matlab .m scripts!

### <s>[Scalala](http://code.google.com/p/scalala/)</s> is now superseded by [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze)

> A high performance numeric linear algebra library for Scala, with rich
> Matlab-like operators on vectors and matrices; a library of numerical
> routines; support for plotting.

### [Factorie](http://factorie.cs.umass.edu/)

> FACTORIE is a toolkit for deployable probabilistic modeling,
> implemented as a software library in Scala. It provides its users with
> a succinct language for creating relational **factor graphs**, estimating
> parameters and performing inference.

### [Cassovary](https://github.com/twitter/cassovary)

by twitter for graph processing:

> Cassovary is designed from the ground up to efficiently handle graphs
> with billions of edges. It comes with some common node and graph data
> structures and traversal algorithms. A typical usage is to do
> large-scale graph mining and analysis.
>
> At Twitter, Cassovary forms the bottom layer of a stack that we use to
> power many of our graph-based features, including "Who to Follow" and
> “Similar to.” We also use it for relevance in Twitter Search and the
> algorithms that determine which Promoted Products users will see. Over
> time, we hope to bring more non-proprietary logic from some of those
> product features into Cassovary.

### [Algebird](https://github.com/twitter/algebird)

Abstract algebra library from twitter:

> Code is targeted at building aggregation systems (via Scalding or
> Storm). It was originally developed as part of Scalding's Matrix API,
> where Matrices had values which are elements of Monoids, Groups, or
> Rings. Subsequently, it was clear that the code had broader
> application within Scalding and on other projects within Twitter.

### [scala_prob](https://github.com/urso/scala_prob)

! has experimental status !

> sb_probdsl offers simple discrete probabilistic programming support
> using scala's new delimited continuations support.

### [Malakov](https://github.com/runarorama/Malakov)

> A Markov Chain library for Scala
>
> Markov chains represent stochastic processes where the probability
> distribution of the next step depends non-trivially on the current
> step, but does not depend on previous steps. Give this library some
> training data and it will generate new random data that statistically
> resembles it.

### [signal-collect](https://github.com/uzh/signal-collect)

> Signal/Collect is a programming model and framework for large-scale
> graph processing. The model is expressive enough to concisely
> formulate many iterated and data-flow algorithms on graphs, while
> allowing the framework to transparently parallelize the processing.

### [Grizzled.math](http://software.clapper.org/grizzled-scala/api/grizzled/math/index.html)

> Includes stat and utility packages. Contains very basic and well known
> things, such as means  std...

### [Probability Monad:](https://github.com/jliszka/probability-monad)

> While it is not library it could help you a lot with dealing
> probabilities.

Comment: You can look at performance comparisons of Scalala and Scalalab vs Python [here](http://mwongstyle.com/wordpress/?p=60)

Comment: There is also [Saddle](http://saddle.github.com/): *Saddle is a data manipulation library for Scala that provides array-backed, indexed, one- and two-dimensional data structures that are judiciously specialized on JVM primitives to avoid the overhead of boxing and unboxing.*

Comment: om-nom-nom, you should raise Saddle to an answer. +1

Comment: @SimeonFitch I'm waiting for a bit of free time, to take a closer look at saddle and perhaps write something more than above excerpt.

Comment: @om-nom-nom : Your link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Figaro is a Scala library for Probabilistic Programming. You could find more information about Figaro here [Figaro Reference](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/avi-pfeffer/figaro.pdf)

Figaro is available for download from [Figaro Github](https://github.com/p2t2/figaro)

The author of this library is currently writing a book on Probabilistic Programming using Figaro. Here is the link to the book page: [Probabilistic Programming Book](https://www.manning.com/books/practical-probabilistic-programming)

Answer (score 1):

### [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire)

> Spire is a numeric library for Scala which is intended to be generic,
>   fast, and precise.
>
> Using features such as specialization, macros, type classes, and
>   implicits, Spire works hard to defy conventional wisdom around
>   performance and precision trade-offs. A major goal is to allow
>   developers to write efficient numeric code without having to "bake in"
>   particular numeric representations. In most cases, generic
>   implementations using Spire's specialized type classes perform
>   identically to corresponding direct implementations.