# Linear algebra library for Scala?

Tags: scala, linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good math/stats library for Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760925/is-there-a-good-math-stats-library-for-scala)

I'm looking for a linear algebra library for Scala (for implementing a Random Forests algorithm). However, it seems there are many Scala LA libraries and have no clue which to pick.

I've come across [scalala](http://code.google.com/p/scalala/), [ScaLAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/), [ScalaNLP](http://www.scalanlp.org/), [scalalab](http://code.google.com/p/scalalab/), etc...

I'm looking for a library with good documentation which hasn't been abandoned yet.

Mind sharing your experiences with any of the Scala linear algebra libraries? Which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See http://www.scalanlp.org/ where [Breeze](https://github.com/dlwh/breeze) is the merger of the ScalaNLP and Scalala projects

Comment: Thanks! I looked into it, I'll be using this as framework :)

Comment: I understand that you have already accepted the answer. But, if you wanted to check out some benchmarks, check this out as well [LinearAlgebra](http://statr.me/2015/09/an-overview-of-linear-algebra-libraries-in-scala-java/). This was very useful to me.