# which is a good vector operations class in scala

Tags: scala

I am doing some Machine Learning code in Scala. I want to vectorize the operations like vector dot product, vector - scalar multiplication, vector vector addition. For example,

```
val x = u . v
val x = 2 * v
```

Basically I have experince in Matlab and would love to have similar operators on vectors. Which is the way to proceed? Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @MikeW I think we need to be a bit more careful with the trigger finger on Stackoverflow. This is a valid question from a newbie, and besides it's not like there are two dozen vector libraries for Scala, so the danger of primarily opinion based answer is not given IMO.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545313/linear-algebra-library-for-scala)

Comment: @0__ Were this a request related to a more mainstream product it would have been mercilessly savaged as off-topic. Looking at the balance of upvotes to close votes I'd say the balance is about even. Perhaps we should agree to differ?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at the [`VectorSpace`](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spire/algebra/VectorSpace.scala) trait, provided by [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire).

Since it supports **generic numeric programming**, you can easily switch between different vector types. See **[this example](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/spire/example/kmeans.scala)** of a k-means clustering algorithm.