# Scala environment for statistical computing and graphics?

Tags: scala, graphics, statistics

Please advise on Scala environment for statistical computing and graphics similar to R or Weka.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest Breeze : http://www.scalanlp.org/ , https://github.com/dlwh/breeze/
It has some predefined Classifiers, Learning Algorithms (SVM , Regeression...), a Plotting Library and support for matrix Multiplication.

Here you can get a quick overview: https://github.com/dlwh/breeze/wiki/Quickstart

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [Scalalab](https://code.google.com/p/scalalab/) is what you're looking for.

> The scripting language is based on the Scala programming language
>   enhanced with high level scientific operators and with an integrated
>   environment that provides a Matlab-like working style. Also, all the
>   huge libraries of Java scientific code can be easily accessible (and
>   many times with a more convenient syntax). [...]  A major design
>   priority of ScalaLab is its user-friendly interface.

See also [Is there a good math/stats library for Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760925/is-there-a-good-math-stats-library-for-scala/8760991#8760991)

Comment: Thanks! How about ploting functions? in Scalalab? Can I for example do something like  hist(rnorm(15)) which in R plots a histogram of 15 random numbers?

Comment: The [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/scalalab/w/list) pages are [pretty explanatory](https://code.google.com/p/scalalab/wiki/PlottingExamples).

Comment: Scalalab is not available for build tools like ivy/mvn/sbt yet :/