# How to solve a large sparse linear system from Scala

Tags: scala, linear-algebra, solver

There have been a few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760925/is-there-a-good-math-stats-library-for-scala) inquiring about general math/stats frameworks for Scala.

I am interested in only one specific problem, that of solving a large sparse linear system. Essentially I am looking for an equivalent of [`scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html).

Currently I am looking into [`breeze-math`](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/tree/master/math) of [ScalaNLP Breeze](http://www.scalanlp.org/breeze-0-1/), which looks like it would do the job, except that the focus of this library collection is natural language processing, so it feels a bit strange to use that.

[Saddle](http://saddle.github.io/) also looks promising, but not very mature yet, and looking at its dependencies, EJML doesn't seem to have sparse functionality, while Apache commons math did, but it was [flaky](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-870).

Has anyone got a reasonably simple and efficient solution that is currently available?

Comment: Any helpful suggestions from the voters-to-close?

Comment: [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/linalg/Algebra.html) is still my go-to library for this kind of thing (but I know I should give Breeze another try one of these days).

Comment: I'm sure the closers will cite the "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library blah blah blah" language. Personally I think this is a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although ScalaNLP Breeze says it's for NLP, it's linear algebra library is fairly general and not specialized to NLP. With that said, you could easily do something like this:

```
  val A = new CSCMatrix[Int]()
  val B = new CSCMatrix[Int]()

  val x = A \ B
```